# Join multiple tables as a return in PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to "not express" return type of a function that return a select of a joined tables because a have a lot of columns and i don't want to write them manually
Myfunction looks like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION selectJoin()
RETURNS SETOF ???
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT t1.*, t2.*
                 FROM t1, t2
                 WHERE t1.t2_id = t2.id;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: Writing them manually is your only choice: `returns table (col1 type1, col2 type2, ...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name same thing for procedure ? i'm sorry for the stupid questions i'm new to postgre

Comment: Do you actually need all those columns?

Comment: @Bergi : Yes i do

Comment: Why don't you create a VIEW?

Comment: procedures aren't meant to return results. Use a function with `returns table()`. But Frank is right: a VIEW sounds like a much better approach.